# Time complexity of a loop

Tags: java, loops, time-complexity

I'm not sure if I'm getting the correct time complexity, any guidance will be appreciated.

```
int count =0;
for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
{ 
    for (int j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
         count ++
    }
}
```

Im working out logn, not sure if my maths is off.

Comment: It's not log(n), it's O(n*i).

Comment: I believe this is `O(n^2)`

Comment: thanks will check it out now, both duplicate and maths on my part